# Removing CKEditor toolbar buttons but not the functionality

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, toolbar

I need to remove some of CKEditor toolbar buttons such as Form but if I remove them with:

```
config.removeButtons = 'Form, ... etc
```

The functionality is also removed, such that if a user pastes in a form it gets auto-deleted!

How do you remove the toolbar buttons without effecting the content?

Form buttons need removing as users will otherwise use them inappropriately, but if they paste in say a paypal form button that should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of Advanced Content Filter working in fully automatic mode. In this mode CKEditor only allows the content that is backed up by its current toolbar configuration.

You need to adjust ACF to accept the additional elements that are not supported by the toolbar config.

Have a look at the following resources to figure it out:

- [Content Filtering](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_acf)
- [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter)
- [Allowed Content Rules](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules)
- [Advanced Content Filter – Automatic Mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acf.html) sample
- [Advanced Content Filter – Custom Mode](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/acfcustom.html) sample

Comment: Thanks, must say looking through that most is clear as mud, but

I`ve put:

[code]config.extraAllowedContent = 'form option checkbox input radio textfield textarea select button image imagebutton hiddenfield;*[*]';[/code]

which seems to work, anything I`ve missed or could be done better?